# Ajax XMLHttpRequest object limit

Tags: ajax

Is there a security limit to the number of Ajax [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) objects you can create on a single page? If so, does this vary from one browser to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but there's a limit of two simultaneous HTTP connections per domain per client (you can override this in Firefox, but practically no one does so).

Comment: Nowadays, this limit is higher, e.g. on my current Firefox (3.6.3/Linux) the default number of simultaneous HTTP connections is 6. You can test it with [this little test case](http://www.spasche.net/files/parallel_connections/).

Answer (score 1):

I've found it easier to pool and reuse XMLHTTPRequest objects instead of creating new ones...

Comment: Agreed, but that doesn't work if you want to have multiple simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Kevin says, HTTP/1.1 specifications say "A single-user client should not maintain more than 2 connections with any server or proxy."