# "XMLHttpRequest Exception 101" on nested AJAX queries

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm doing an AJAX fetch of a binary file the I am parsing in javascript. (Quake 2 BSPs, if anyone cares.) The code to fetch and parse the initial file is working fine, and looks roughly like this:

```
function loadFile(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            var parsed = parseFile(request.responseText);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    request.send(null);
}
```

As I said, that works fine, and everything loads and parses correctly. However, the file also describes several secondary files (textures) that need to be retrieved as well, and so I've added an inner loop that should load and parse all of those files, like so:

```
function loadFile(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            var parsed = parseFile(request.responseText);
            for(var i = 0; i < parsed.files.length; ++i) {
                loadSecondaryFile(parsed.files[i].url); // Request code here is identical to this function
            }
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    request.send(null);
}

function loadSecondaryFile(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            var parsed = parseSecondaryFile(request.responseText);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    request.send(null);
}
```

But every request made from within that loop immediately fails with the message (in Chrome, Dev Channel): **NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101** This strikes me as strange, since if I call `loadSecondaryFile` outside of `loadFile` it works perfectly.

My initial impression was that initiating an one ajax call in the `onreadystatechage` of another may be bad juju, but wrapping the secondary ajax calls in a `setTimer` doesn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the `loadSecondaryFile` function?

Comment: As I mentioned in the quesion, the request portion is identical to loadFile, but I'll post it anyway to avoid confusion.

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < parsed.files.length; ++i) {

Should be

for(var i = 0; i < parsed.files.length; i++) {

Not sure if it's the cause.

Comment: Nope, has nothing to do with it. In that context ++i and i++ are functionally identical (though ++i may be faster)

Comment: Have you checked `parsed.files[i].url` is a valid request url?

Comment: Yes, and passing the same url externally brings back the desired file.

Comment: I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217/ajax-xmlhttprequest-object-limit. Maybe try to run it in a series(maybe use jQuery for that) instead of all at once?

Comment: Do you have an example page with this code, so we can test it? And you aren't testing this locally (using file:// protocol), are you? Another thing: what happens if you do this asynchronously (FYI, set the third parameter of `request.open` to `false`)?

Comment: I am testing locally, but using a django as a static file server to do so. (Otherwise ajax doesn't work at all.) And setting the third param of `open` to false indicates <b>synchronous</b> transactions, not asynchronous.

Comment: Indeed, but still, what happens if you try that? BTW, many browsers *can* handle file:// connections using XMLHttpRequest (though that hasn't much to do with HTTP, of course), only Chrome chokes on that. I just tested your code using my own web servers (local and remote), trying to get 10 files simultaneously, but every file was retrieved properly (tested with Firefox 3.6.3 and Chromium 5.0.375.70 on Linux), only the order differed (I used an object like `{ files: [ {url: "xhr-loop-0" }, { url: "xhr-loop-1" }, … ] }`).

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser! I have discovered that, even in the loop, if I request the url of a static string (for example 'textures/tex1.png') I succeed every single time. However, if the url that I provide it is build dynamically (ie: 'textures/' + tex.name + '.png') the request fails immediately every time. I am printing the urls that I'm requesting to the console, and they all appear correct, and I can copy any one of them and request it as a static string and it works. Is this some sort of insane security measure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And... SUCCESS! So I feel really stupid, and I realize now that there's no way anyone else could have given me a solution with the information I presented. Terribly sorry!

It has nothing to do with AJAX and everything to do with how I was getting my URLs. Recall that I mentioned I was loading binary data from a Quake2 bsp, in this case, texture paths. Textures in the bsp format are stored as fixed length 32 bit strings with null padding. I was reading them using substr like so:

`var path = fileBuffer.substr(fileOffset, 32);`

Which I thought was giving me a string like "e2u3/clip", but in reality was giving me "e2u3/clip\0\0\0\0..." Of course, when printed this would look correct (since console.log represents the null char as nothing.) but the browser recognized it immediately as a bad URL and tossed it out.

Changing my read code to:

`var path = fileBuffer.substr(fileOffset, 32).replace(/\0+$/,'');`

Gives me valid strings and fixes all of my apparent AJAX problems! *sigh*

Thanks for all the suggestions! It helped put me on the right track.